# Function for receive notifcation alert in websocket php?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I am working in Php with websockets for "one to one chat" module,I am new in "websockets", Here is my code

```
<script>
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8282');
    
    var client = {
        user_id: <?php echo $user_id; ?>,
        recipient_id: null,
        type: 'socket',
        token: null,
        message: null
    };

    conn.onopen = function (e) {
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(client));
        $('#messages').append('<font color="green">Successfully connected as user ' + client.user_id + '</font><br>');
    };

    conn.onmessage = function (e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (data.message) {
            $('#messages').append(data.user_id + ' : ' + data.message + '<br>');
        }
        if (data.type === 'token') {
            $('#token').html('JWT Token : ' + data.token);
        }
    };

    $('#submit').click(function () {
        
        client.message = $('#text').val();
        
        $('#messages').append(client.message + '<br>');
        
        client.token = $('#token').text().split(': ')[1];
        client.type = 'chat';
        if ($('#recipient_id').val()) {
            client.recipient_id = $('#recipient_id').val();
        }
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(client));
    });
</script>
```

I want to know that

1. can we set "Userid" from our side ? or this "Userid" is issued by server ?
2. we are using "conn.onmessage" for receive message but which function should be use for receive "notifcation" (when specific notification come for specific user) ?

Comment: What do you mean? There's no such concept as a "notification" in the websocket protocol, there are just messages. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket for the functions and callbacks available in the JS client. If a message has come from a particular user, that information will need to be part of the message data which the server sends, and your JS code in the onmessage callback will need to parse the message and use the information however it needs to